# How to retrieve data from mysql and display it in a view using django

Tags: python, django

Here is my model:

```
  from django.db import models

    # Create your models here.
    class Contact(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=125, null=True)
        email = models.EmailField()
        address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

I am trying to display data in a view:

```
<div class="row d-block">
    <table class="table table-responsive">



  <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <th>Email:</th>
                <th>Address:</th>
                <th>City:</th>
                <th>Zipcode:</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in rows%}
        <tr>
            <th>{{rows.name}}</th>
            <th>{{rows.emai}}</th>
            <th>{{rows.address}}</th>
            <th>{{rows.city}}</th>
            <th>{{rows.zipcode}}</th>
        </tr>
        {%endfor%}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my function where I send data in the db.
My next step is to retrieve the data from  db and display it in html:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from pages.models import Contact
    # from django.views import View
    # Create your views here.
    def home(request):
      return render(request, 'index.html', {'title':'Home Page'})
    def contact(request):

      if(request.method == 'POST'):
        data = Contact(
          name = request.POST['name'],
          email = request.POST['email'], 
          address = request.POST['address'],
          city = request.POST['city'],
          zipcode = request.POST['zipcode'],  

        )
        data.save()

        dbdata = Contact.objects.all()
        print(dbdata)
      return render(request, 'contact.html',  {'title':'Contact Page','row':dbdata})
```

When I try to retrieve data from db, the following error occurs:

```
UnboundLocalError at /pages/contact/
local variable 'dbdata' referenced before assignment
```

How can I retrieve and display my data?

Comment: it should be `{{ row.name }}` not `{{ rows.name }}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display data from db in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037667/display-data-from-db-in-django)

Answer (score 3):

There is a mistake in passing context.. you are using key **row** in contex.But you are calling **rows** in for loop.change key **row** to **rows** . and keep for loop as it is.

> here change in passing context dictinary key

```
return render(request, 'contact.html',  {'title':'Contact Page','rows':dbdata})
```

please let me know if it is workin or not..

Answer (score 1):

You should move `dbdata` declaration out of `if(request.method == 'POST'):` block:

```
def contact(request):

  if(request.method == 'POST'):
    data = Contact(
      name = request.POST['name'],
      email = request.POST['email'], 
      address = request.POST['address'],
      city = request.POST['city'],
      zipcode = request.POST['zipcode'],  

    )
    data.save()

  dbdata = Contact.objects.all()
  print(dbdata)
  return render(request, 'contact.html',  {'title':'Contact Page','row':dbdata})
```

Otherwise in case of `GET` request block of code inside if statement never reached and you'll see this error.

Also in template you should replace `rows` with `row` inside for loop:

```
{% for row in rows%}
    <tr>
        <th>{{row.name}}</th> 
        <th>{{row.emai}}</th>
        <th>{{row.address}}</th>
        <th>{{row.city}}</th>
        <th>{{row.zipcode}}</th>
    </tr>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: And instead of ```<th>{{rows.###}}</th>``` use ```<th>{{row.###}}</th>```