# display data from db in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying retrive data from db and  display in view but output is
empty. Here is my function

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from pages.models import Contact
# from django.views import View
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
  return render(request, 'index.html', {'title':'Home Page'})
def contact(request):

  if(request.method == 'POST'):
    data = Contact(
      name = request.POST['name'],
      email = request.POST['email'], 
      address = request.POST['address'],
      city = request.POST['city'],
      zipcode = request.POST['zipcode'],  

    )
    data.save()

  dbdata = Contact.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'contact.html',  {'title':'Contact Page','row':dbdata})
```

Here is my template and display data in this table

```
  <tbody>

            {% for row in rows %}
            <tr>
                <th>{{row.name}}</th> 
                <th>{{row.emai}}</th>
                <th>{{row.address}}</th>
                <th>{{row.city}}</th>
                <th>{{row.zipcode}}</th>
            </tr>
        {%endfor%} 
        </tbody>
```

I am beginner in django.and also please tell me how to debug code in
django.

Comment: In view it should be `rows`: return render(request, 'contact.html',  {'title':'Contact Page','rows':dbdata}).

Answer (score 4):

there is a mistake in passing context.. you are using key **row** in contex.But you are calling **rows** in for loop.change key **row** to **rows** . and keep for loop as it is.

> here change in passing context dictinary key

```
return render(request, 'contact.html',  {'title':'Contact Page','rows':dbdata})
```

if this is working then let me know....

Answer (score 1):

replace follwoing code in view.py [you just made a mistake at **row**'s name ]

> **make sure your code in proper alignment**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from pages.models import Contact
# from django.views import View
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
  return render(request, 'index.html', {'title':'Home Page'})
def contact(request):

  if(request.method == 'POST'):
    data = Contact(
      name = request.POST['name'],
      email = request.POST['email'], 
      address = request.POST['address'],
      city = request.POST['city'],
      zipcode = request.POST['zipcode'],  

    )
    data.save()

    dbdata = Contact.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'contact.html',  {'title':'Contact Page','rows':dbdata})
```

and add following code in HTML

```
 <tbody>
        {% for row in rows %}
             <tr>
                <th>{{row.name}}</th> 
                <th>{{row.emai}}</th>
                <th>{{row.address}}</th>
                <th>{{row.city}}</th>
                <th>{{row.zipcode}}</th>
            </tr>
        {%endfor%}
</tbody>
```